# Strange behaviour with index

Tags: pandas

I have a large DataFrame indexed by datetime of the type below

`2013-07-15 09:30:00.073000,-0.909437,0.287493,-0.071288`

When I try the following code I get a result

```
tempdf[tempdf.index[1]:tempdf.index[2]]
```

but when I try

```
tempdf[tempdf.index[2]]
```

I get the following error

`KeyError: u'no item named 2013-07-15 09:30:00.076000'`

In fact code of the following type also errors out.

```
tempdf[tempdf.index[3]:tempdf.index[8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using an indexing short-cut which doesn't apply, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#datetime-indexing

Create a time indexed frame

```
In [7]: df = DataFrame(randn(10,2),columns=list('AB'),index=date_range('20130101',periods=10))

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
                   A         B
2013-01-01 -1.423000  0.455915
2013-01-02 -0.665164 -0.057901
2013-01-03  2.446799 -1.788711
2013-01-04  0.054663  0.254730
2013-01-05 -0.371827 -0.775781
2013-01-06  0.275138 -1.221521
2013-01-07  1.338971  0.652810
2013-01-08  0.454797 -0.966469
2013-01-09  0.942590  0.302687
2013-01-10 -0.587606 -0.562724
```

This is a convenience that a slice selects on the rows

```
In [9]: df[df.index[1]:df.index[2]]
Out[9]: 
                   A         B
2013-01-02 -0.665164 -0.057901
2013-01-03  2.446799 -1.788711
```

This gives you an error because it looking for a column (you passed a single value)

```
In [10]: df[df.index[2]]
KeyError: u'no item named 2013-01-03 00:00:00'
```

Here is the method of selecting without ambiguity

select a single item from the rows

```
In [11]: df.loc[df.index[2]]
Out[11]: 
A    2.446799
B   -1.788711
Name: 2013-01-03 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Select a range from the rows

```
In [12]: df.loc[df.index[2]:df.index[3]]
Out[12]: 
                   A         B
2013-01-03  2.446799 -1.788711
2013-01-04  0.054663  0.254730
```

Select from the columns

```
In [13]: df.loc[:,'A']
Out[13]: 
2013-01-01   -1.423000
2013-01-02   -0.665164
2013-01-03    2.446799
2013-01-04    0.054663
2013-01-05   -0.371827
2013-01-06    0.275138
2013-01-07    1.338971
2013-01-08    0.454797
2013-01-09    0.942590
2013-01-10   -0.587606
Freq: D, Name: A, dtype: float64
```

If wes did this all over again, I think this api wouldn't be allowed....but too entrenched
the `[]` selection is WAY overloaded and pandas tries its best to figure out what you want